# How to disable cors on azure APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have enabled the cors policy in azure APIM(portal overview)for developer portal now I want to disable that cors policy? I have tried but there no any button to disable it. Can you help me on this. Please have a look at attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try go to `APIs=> All APIs => delete cors policy => save`.

[image]

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: Thanks bro, You saved my day

Comment: @MrKunwar ,have a nice day!